# How to spread maxWidth property as max-width on a React component? If I pass it down as maxWidth property I get an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I am getting the following error because I'm probably not spreading the maxWidth property correctly:

Warning: React does not recognize the `maxWidth` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `maxwidth` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

I believe the error stems from the way I'm spreading the properties to the component:

```
export const Card = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, CardProps>(
  ({ outline, elevation, width = 'inherit', maxWidth='650px', isModal, ...props }, ref) => {
    const CardWrapper = isModal ? DialogWrapper : Wrapper 
    return (
      <CardWrapper
        ref={ref}
        {...{ outline, elevation, width, maxWidth, ...props }}
      >
        <CardContent {...{ elevation, isModal, ...props }} />
      </CardWrapper>
    )
  }
)
```

As you can see I'm spreading `maxWidth='650px'` when it should be `max-width='650'`. The problem is that I'm not sure how to spread it using an alias or something

Comment: `max-width` is usually a style (CSS) property, rather than an HTML attribute, which DOM element are you adding it to?

Answer (score 1):

`maxWidth` is actually not a prop on a DOM element. maxWidth is a style and should be used like this `<div style={{maxWidth:'650px'}}>` or else your `CardWrapper` accepts `maxWidth` as prop